# How to export an object with Browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, browserify

I started using Browserify and not sure if I completely understand how to use it.

I have a file with some functions bundled in one object in `foo.js`

```
var foo = {
  f1: function(){...}
  f2: function(){...}
}

module.exports = function () {
  return foo;
};
```

And I want to export them to a variable in the `main.js` file, so I tried doing this:

```
var bar = require('/foo')();
```

The goal is to be able to do `bar.f1()`.
Without executing `require('/foo')` I get only a function definition, so I have to execute it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you export a function, `require()` will return that function.  What don't you understand?

Comment: @SLaks how stupid.. I was sure I have to export a function with a return value. Got it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just export the object:

```
var foo = {
  f1: function(){...}
  f2: function(){...}
};

module.exports = foo;
```